# AWS Amplify publish to a custom domain

Tags: aws-amplify

I just completed the tutorial on AWS Amplify and I will have to say it is impressive. I have one question though. On the final step of the [tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/hosting/q/integration/react#publish-your-app) the app is published and will be exposed to the public in the domain .amplifyapp.com. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to use another custom domain instead?

Thank you.

Comment: You should look at the aws console user guide, there you will find two options. You could either register your domain to hosted zones in Route53 in the aws console, or you can configure it by updating the dns records directly in the aws amplify console.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-amazon-route-53.html